# Optimizing SQL query with a single join

Tags: sql, hana

I need help optimizing my query as our SAP HANA environment keeps failing trying to run the below.

I'm simply trying to get YTD invoice data and whether or not the invoice is open.  We store invoice lines and their status (open/closed) and unfortunately, we don't store an invoice number per se but the invoice number is stored in one of two fields depending on the "Sales_Document_Type".

As such, I've written the below query to retrieve all invoices, a CASE statement flag to identify open/closed and the last Clearing_Date.  I am fairly certain this will work but I am looking for help suggesting ways to optimize it as it cannot be processed in its current form.

```sql
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN A."Sales_Document_Type" IN ('A','B','C') THEN A."Accounting_Document_No"
    ELSE A."Assignment_Number" END AS "Invoice_Number",
    CASE
        WHEN A."Sales_Document_Type" IN ('A','B','C') THEN (
        CASE
            WHEN B."Accounting_Document_No" IS NULL THEN 'C'
        ELSE 'O' END
        )
    ELSE (
        CASE
            WHEN B."Accounting_Document_No" IS NULL THEN 'C'
        ELSE 'O' END
        ) 
    END AS "Open_Close_Flag",
     MAX(A."Clearing_Date") AS "Clearing_Date"

FROM 
    "AccountsReceivable" A

LEFT JOIN 
    "AccountsReceivable" B ON (A."Assignment_Number" = B."Assignment_Number" OR A."Accounting_Document_No" = B."Accounting_Document_No") AND B."OpenClose_Flag" = 'O' AND B."Creation_Date" >= '2019-01-01'

WHERE
    A."Creation_Date" >= '2019-01-01'

GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN A."Sales_Document_Type" IN ('A','B','C') THEN A."Accounting_Document_No"
    ELSE A."Assignment_Number" END,
    CASE
        WHEN A."Sales_Document_Type" IN ('A','B','C') THEN (
        CASE
            WHEN B."Accounting_Document_No" IS NULL THEN 'C' 
        ELSE 'O' END
        )
    ELSE (
        CASE
            WHEN B."Accounting_Document_No" IS NULL THEN 'C'
        ELSE 'O' END
        ) 
    END
```

Sample data in the "AccountsReceivable" table would look like this (labels abbreviated):

```
Sales_Doc_Type | Accounting_Doc_# | Assignment_# | Line | OpenClose_F | Clearing_Date
A              | 1234             | 5678         | 1    | O           | 
A              | 1234             | 5678         | 2    | C           | 2019-10-01
C              | 1235             | 5679         | 1    | O           | 
D              | 1001             | 9876         | 1    | O           | 
D              | 1001             | 9876         | 2    | C           | 2019-10-01
D              | 1002             | 9870         | 1    | C           | 2019-10-05
D              | 1002             | 9870         | 2    | C           | 2019-10-09
```

Important to note that the documents have multiple lines and each line can be open (OpenClose_Flag of O) or closed (C).  My desired output is either the Accounting_Document_No or the Assignment_Number AS Invoice_Number (depending on the sales_document_type), an O if any line is O or C if all lines are C and the max clearing_date:

```
Invoice_Number | OpenClose_Flag | MAX(Clearing_Date)
1234           | O              | 2019-10-01
1235           | O              |
9876           | O              | 2019-10-01
9870           | C              | 2019-10-09
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Please describe the logic you want to implement.  Sample data and desired results would help.  The logic around your "invoices" is almost impossible to understand without sample data.

Comment: good point, i've just edited the original post to include some sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain the query produces the results you are looking for, you need to look at the query execution plan and optimize there.

Sometimes it's not the query that needs addressing but the table.

This particular query is large but very bland:

```
SELECT (SOME BASIC STUFF)
FROM Table1 A 
    LEFT JOIN Table1 B on (JOIN CONDITION)
WHERE
    (FILTER CONDITION)
GROUP BY (FOUND IN SELECT)
```

To optimize the execution plan:

- Make sure your filter condition is indexed.
- Make sure your join condition is indexed (and not partial joining)

The OR condition in your join makes it hard to create a ideal indexed, use the two below as a guideline to see which one the system picks and drop the other.

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_AccountsReceivable_Creation_Date_OpenClose_Flag_Accounting_Document_No ON AccountsReceivable (Creation_Date, OpenClose_Flag, Accounting_Document_No)
CREATE INDEX IDX_AccountsReceivable_Accounting_Creation_Date_OpenClose_Flag_Assignment_Number ON AccountsReceivable (Creation_Date, OpenClose_Flag, Assignment_Number)
```

If your working with a subset of data, make sure your conditions are triggering your indexes and not doing a table/index scan as such:
[image]

Comment: These tips may work on MS SQL but for HANA additional indexes - especially multi column indexes - are rarely the best solution.

Comment: Silly me, I mistakenly thought that was a BI tool that worked on top of SQL Server, turns out it's its own dbms.   Indexing is a pretty generic database concept.   If it doesn't work here than that's a bummer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm a lowly consumer of the data in this situation and am unable to change the structure of the tables, index fields, etc.  I don't even know which fields are indexed though I suspect Creation_Date is... at least for this particular table it's a logical field to index.

Answer (score 0):

First up: to determine whether this would actually improve performance, a reasonable volume of test data is required. With the few sample rows provided, all we can do is to see if the result matches the expectation, but the runtime differences will typically be in the margin of runtime variability.

With that disclaimer here my approach for an answer.

The main problem of the original statement is that it uses constructs that are hard to run in parallel and over sets of records. The `CASE` expressions need to be evaluated for every single row and the `JOIN` forces a synchronisation point in the processing data flow.

To avoid both, I replaced the `CASE` constructs with separating the different `"Invoice_Number"` encodings into subsets that are then `UNION`ed together.
Based on this, I determine "Invoice_Numbers" that have no open invoices left, i.e. those groups are considered `"C"`losed.

All remaining groups are then considered `"O"`pen.

The final statement looks like this:

```
with base as (
    SELECT
         "Assignment_#"          AS "Invoice_Number"
       , "OpenClose_F"
       , "Clearing_Date"
       , "Creation_date"
    FROM 
        "AccountsReceivable" 
    WHERE
         "Sales_Doc_Type" NOT IN ('A','B','C')
      and "Creation_date" >= '2019-01-01'
UNION ALL 
    SELECT
         "Accounting_Doc_#"          AS "Invoice_Number"
       , "OpenClose_F"
       , "Clearing_Date"
       , "Creation_date"
    FROM 
        "AccountsReceivable" 
    WHERE
         "Sales_Doc_Type" IN ('A','B','C')
      AND "Creation_date" >= '2019-01-01' ),
closed as (
            select 
                 "Invoice_Number"
               , 'C' as "OpenClose_F"
               , max("Clearing_Date") as max_clearing_date
            from base b
            where NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                             FROM base
                             where "Invoice_Number" = b."Invoice_Number"
                             and "OpenClose_F" = 'O')
            group by "Invoice_Number"
                     , 'C'),
open as (
        select 
             "Invoice_Number"
           , 'O' as "OpenClose_F"
           , max("Clearing_Date") as max_clearing_date
        from base b
        where NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                         FROM closed
                         where "Invoice_Number" = b."Invoice_Number")
        group by "Invoice_Number"
                 , 'O')

select 'O' as grp
     , "Invoice_Number"
     , "OpenClose_F"
     , max_clearing_date
from open
union all
select 'C' as grp
     , "Invoice_Number"
     , "OpenClose_F"
     , max_clearing_date
from closed
```

This approach also allows for additional tuning via indexing and partitioning if the data allows for that.